# How to boost document based on keywords in apache solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solr-boost, lucidworks

I am using apache solr 4.10. I have to boost documents against which they are served so that they will have better score. Now for that, I have to log that document id as well as that query.

How to save document id and query ?

Second, I have to use that information to boost that document. How should I do it?

Comment: This is what the [query elevation component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component) was built for (at least, to take certain documents to the top for a given query).

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you asking for: do you mean you have to increase the score for the most viewed documents in a query?

Comment: yes that's what I have asked